# How to fix error “SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) stopped automatically?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am not able to login in my SQL server. I am getting this error message when I am trying to connect it.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

When I look SQL Server Configuration manager then I have observed that my "SQL SERVER (MSSQLSERVER)" is being stopped automatically with in couple of seconds. I have tries to started yet but still it's being stopped.

Have any one any idea on same.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7d1R.png)

Here the error log also

```
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.01 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2014 -
> 12.0.4213.0 (Intel X86)   Jun  9 2015 12:17:04    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build
> 7601: ) (WOW64)
> 
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.01 Server      UTC adjustment: 5:30 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.01 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.01 Server      All rights reserved. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.01
> Server      Server process ID is 3840. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.01 Server  
> System Manufacturer: 'Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.', System Model:
> 'To be filled by O.E.M.'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.01 Server     
> Authentication mode is MIXED. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.01 Server     
> Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.01 Server      The service account is 'NT
> Service\MSSQLSERVER'. This is an informational message; no user action
> is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.01 Server      Registry startup
> parameters:    -d C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf   -e C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG      -l
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.01 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:   -s
> "MSSQLSERVER" 2016-05-24 12:56:11.23 Server      SQL Server detected 1
> sockets with 2 cores per socket and 4 logical processors per socket, 4
> total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL
> Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is
> required. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.23 Server      SQL Server is starting at
> normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No
> user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.23 Server      Detected
> 3989 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is
> required. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.23 Server      Using conventional memory
> in the memory manager. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.24 Server      Buffer pool
> extension is not supported on the 32-bit architecture. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.24 Server      Default collation:
> SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033) 2016-05-24 12:56:11.26
> Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections
> for this instance is '1' 2016-05-24 12:56:11.26 Server      This
> instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 2632 at
> 5/24/2016 12:51:45 PM (local) 5/24/2016 7:21:45 AM (UTC). This is an
> informational message only; no user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.26 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask:
> 0x0000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000f:0. This message provides a
> description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.26 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial
> allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node. 
> This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.27 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.27 spid11s     Starting up database 'master'.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.31 spid11s     28 transactions rolled forward in
> database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No
> user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.31 spid11s     0
> transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0). This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.37 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.41 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality
> initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.52
> spid11s     SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an
> informational message. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.52 spid11s     SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This
> is an informational message. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.53 spid11s     SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.53 spid11s     Server name is 'AZURE'. This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.66 spid17s     A new instance of the full-text filter daemon
> host process has been successfully started. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.81
> spid19s     Starting up database 'msdb'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.81
> spid20s     Starting up database 'ReportServer'. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.81 spid21s     Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.81 spid16s     A self-generated certificate was
> successfully loaded for encryption. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.81 spid22s    
> Starting up database '360IT'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.81 spid23s    
> Starting up database 'True_Athuntication_Release_1'. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.82 spid16s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.82 spid16s     Server is listening on [ 'any'
> <ipv4> 1433]. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.82 spid16s     Server local
> connection provider is ready to accept connection on [
> \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ]. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.82 spid16s    
> Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [
> \\.\pipe\sql\query ]. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.82 Server      Server is
> listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434]. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.82 Server     
> Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434]. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.82 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was
> established for listening locally on port 1434. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.82
> spid16s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an
> informational message; no user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.82 Server      SQL Server is attempting to register a Service
> Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Kerberos
> authentication will not be possible until a SPN is registered for the
> SQL Server service. This is an informational message. No user action
> is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.82 Server      The SQL Server Network
> Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN)
> [ MSSQLSvc/azure ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code:
> 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might cause
> integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an
> informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos
> authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN
> has not been manually registered. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.82 Server     
> The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the
> Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/azure:1433 ] for the SQL
> Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to
> register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM
> instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action
> is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by
> authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually
> registered. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83 spid24s     Starting up database
> 'True_Talent__staging_Release_1'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83 spid12s    
> Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83
> spid35s     Starting up database 'pkk'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83 spid32s
> Starting up database 'True_Athuntication_ver_1'. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:11.83 spid30s     Starting up database 'truehrms_actualdata'.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83 spid31s     Starting up database
> 'TRUEHRM_DEMO'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83 spid27s     Starting up
> database 'True_Talent_Internal_1'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83 spid29s    
> Starting up database 'DEMO_TEST'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83 spid28s    
> Starting up database 'ATSAuthentication_live'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83
> spid25s     Starting up database 'True_Athuntication_Internal_1'.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83 spid33s     Starting up database
> 'True_Talent_ver_1'. 2016-05-24 12:56:11.83 spid34s     Starting up
> database 'hrmlog'. 2016-05-24 12:56:12.05 spid12s     The resource
> database build version is 12.00.4100. This is an informational message
> only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:12.87 spid21s     1
> transactions rolled forward in database 'ReportServerTempDB' (6:0).
> This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:12.92 spid29s     1 transactions rolled forward in
> database 'DEMO_TEST' (13:0). This is an informational message only. No
> user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:12.97 spid34s     1
> transactions rolled forward in database 'hrmlog' (18:0). This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:13.23 spid23s     1 transactions rolled forward in database
> 'True_Athuntication_Release_1' (8:0). This is an informational message
> only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:13.29 spid28s     2
> transactions rolled forward in database 'ATSAuthentication_live'
> (12:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is
> required. 2016-05-24 12:56:13.48 spid21s     0 transactions rolled
> back in database 'ReportServerTempDB' (6:0). This is an informational
> message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:13.50
> spid12s     Recovery completed for database mssqlsystemresource
> (database ID 32767) in 1 second(s) (analysis 380 ms, redo 0 ms, undo
> 218 ms.) This is an informational message only. No user action is
> required. 2016-05-24 12:56:13.60 spid29s     0 transactions rolled
> back in database 'DEMO_TEST' (13:0). This is an informational message
> only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:13.60 spid28s     0
> transactions rolled back in database 'ATSAuthentication_live' (12:0).
> This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:13.83 spid25s     49 transactions rolled forward in
> database 'True_Athuntication_Internal_1' (10:0). This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:13.86 spid35s     Recovery completed for database pkk (database
> ID 19) in 1 second(s) (analysis 165 ms, redo 0 ms, undo 216 ms.) This
> is an informational message only. No user action is required.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:14.15 spid23s     0 transactions rolled back in
> database 'True_Athuntication_Release_1' (8:0). This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:14.15 spid23s     Recovery completed for database
> True_Athuntication_Release_1 (database ID 8) in 1 second(s) (analysis
> 261 ms, redo 0 ms, undo 276 ms.) This is an informational message
> only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:14.76 spid34s     0
> transactions rolled back in database 'hrmlog' (18:0). This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:14.76 spid34s     Recovery completed for database hrmlog
> (database ID 18) in 2 second(s) (analysis 186 ms, redo 89 ms, undo
> 1171 ms.) This is an informational message only. No user action is
> required. 2016-05-24 12:56:14.94 spid20s     1 transactions rolled
> forward in database 'ReportServer' (5:0). This is an informational
> message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:15.17 Logon
> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38. 2016-05-24 12:56:15.17 Logon   
> Login failed for user 'NT SERVICE\ReportServer'. Reason: Failed to
> open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer'. [CLIENT:
> fe80::4cb1:8acf:dce2:e32a%11] 2016-05-24 12:56:15.23 spid32s     1
> transactions rolled forward in database 'True_Athuntication_ver_1'
> (16:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is
> required. 2016-05-24 12:56:15.47 spid25s     0 transactions rolled
> back in database 'True_Athuntication_Internal_1' (10:0). This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:15.47 spid25s     Recovery completed for database
> True_Athuntication_Internal_1 (database ID 10) in 1 second(s)
> (analysis 264 ms, redo 50 ms, undo 1412 ms.) This is an informational
> message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24 12:56:15.66
> spid20s     0 transactions rolled back in database 'ReportServer'
> (5:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is
> required. 2016-05-24 12:56:15.77 spid12s     Starting up database
> 'model'. 2016-05-24 12:56:15.81 spid32s     0 transactions rolled back
> in database 'True_Athuntication_ver_1' (16:0). This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2016-05-24
> 12:56:16.30 spid12s     Error: 9003, Severity: 20, State: 1.
> 2016-05-24 12:56:16.30 spid12s     The log scan number (35:376:1)
> passed to log scan in database 'model' is not valid. This error may
> indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match
> the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication,
> re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the
> problem results in a failure during startup. 2016-05-24 12:56:16.30
> spid12s     SQL Server shutdown has been initiated 2016-05-24
> 12:56:16.30 spid12s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown.
> Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action
> is required.
```

Comment: And the logs say what as the reason?

Comment: Check log or share it

Comment: how can we share the log over here

Answer (score 2):

this is most probably issue with the SQL Server Service. Your service might be in stopped state.

To fix the issue, use following steps:

1. Press Window Button + R
2. Type Services.msc
3. Search for SQL Server Services
4. Select your SQL Server Service instance and click on start on left panel.
5. Make this service as Automatic start/Delayed start in properties by right clicking.

Hope this will solve your problem. If still not able to connect to SQL Server, 
check the errorlog for your instance. Assuming a default instance, you should look in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLSERVER2012\MSSQL\Log

And if nothing helps, your installation appears indeed to be broken. I would try the repair option in the Installation Center.

Also you can get some help from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117972/sql-server-service-automatically-stops-after-starting)

Answer (score 1):

> The log scan number (35:376:1)
>   passed to log scan in database **'model'** is not valid. This error may
>   indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match
>   the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication,
>   re-create the publication.Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup.

So the reason is that your `model` database is corrupt. Either re-install, repair or use hints in the linked answer:

https://serverfault.com/a/497488/229754

Recreating corrupted model database could be tricky, because you need to play with startup flags `–T3608` `–T3609` and SQLCMD [as described here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/the-sql-server-instance-that-will-not-start/).

Answer (score 0):

go to service instance of your server
start-->services--->your server
try to start the dependency "SQL Server Agent",if started then start your sever instance.
if failed to start your server agent,
go to server agent properties(rignt click and then properties), give your pC password ,apply and then try to start. it should work

Answer (score 0):

1. From the search box under Windows Start in Vista or Windows 7, or from Start|Run in Windows XP, enter "services.msc" to show the list of services running on your computer.
2. Look for "SQL Server (SIXBITDBSERVER)" in the list.
3. Right-click on the SQL Server (SIXBITDBSERVER) and select Properties
4. Select the Recovery Tab
5. Set First Failure, Second Failure, and Subsequent Failure to: Restart the Service
6. Set Restart service after to "0" (zero) minutes.
   7.Click Apply & OK

If that does not work, you can try the following instructions for editing the registry.

Caution: Incorrectly editing the registry may severely damage your system. Before making changes to the registry, you should back up any valued data.
To change the service timeout value:

1. Click the Start button, then click Run, type regedit, and click OK.
2. In the Registry Editor, click the registry subkey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control.
3. In the details pane, locate the ServicesPipeTimeout entry, right-click that entry and then select Modify.
   Note: If the ServicesPipeTimeout entry does not exist, you must create it by selecting New on the Edit menu, followed by the DWORD Value, then typing ServicesPipeTimeout, and clicking Enter.
4. Click Decimal, enter the new timeout value in milliseconds (180000 is 3 minutes), and then click OK.
5. Restart the computer.

Answer (score -1):

go to start and type 'services' in this window search for your SQL Server Instance right click and select start, it would be stopped

[image]

Comment: I have tried the same but it's being automatically stopped with in few seconds.

Comment: first start its dependency service called "SQL Server Agent" then try again

Comment: can you provide a snapshot of your services?

Comment: How can we share screen shot over here